# Android: stop sound notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I use NotificationManager to play the sound. But I dont know how to stop it, when I am press any key. For example, back button. Thanks so much.~~~^^

```
NotificationManager manager 
    = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

Notification notification = new Notification(); 
notification.sound=Uri.parse("android.resource://" 
    + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.fin); 

manager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the NotificationManager uses the MediaPlayer to play the sound.
This plays your entire sound by default.
So you need to get a call to mediaplayer.stop.
Have you tried just canceling your notification? [notification Cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29)

Comment: um...yes, i just want to stop it...or quit this notification. 
Anyway, thanks for your reply.